# Calling method with flipped parameters in Java

Tags: java, methods

I have a few subclasses of Shape:

```
Rectangle, Circle, etc.
```

I also have a methods in each class like this:

```
class Rectangle extends Shape{
    public void isIntersecting(Circle circle){ ... }  
}

class Circle extends Shape{
    public void isIntersecting(Rectangle rectangle){ ... }  
}
```

These methods obviously would be repeated code. My question is, how do I avoid something like this?

Comment: I could tell you better how to refactor the functionality if you gave a better example of what the method bodies are. Are they the same exact code, regardless of the method signature?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Obviously circle.isIntersecting(Triangle tri) is not going to have the same code as rectangle.isIntersecting(Triangle tri). Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement them once (in either class or as a static method somewhere) and have all methods call that shared code.

```
class Rectangle extends Shape{
   public boolean isIntersecting(Circle circle){ 
      return Shapes.isIntersecting(this, circle);
   }  
} 

class Circle extends Shape{
   public boolean isIntersecting(Rectangle rectangle){
       return Shapes.isIntersecting(rectangle, this);
   }  
}

class Shapes{
    static boolean isIntersecting(Rectangle rectangle, Circle circle){
       // implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yuck now you have 3 methods when 2 was enuff.

Comment: The alternative is placing the implementation into Rectangle (or Circle), see @Stephen's answer, but I personally would not like to mix Rectangle code into the Circle class. And the Shapes class need not be made public (so it can be invisible to the user).

Comment: This is what I think I might end up doing, but I'll hold off accepting it for now. @mP I agree with Thilo, I'd rather do this then mix the code.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to implement (for instance) Circle's intersection method as:

```
public void isIntersecting(Rectangle rectangle) {
    rectangle.isIntersecting(this);
}
```

I can't think of a more elegant method.

---

The problem with defining the API method as this:

```
public void isIntersecting(Shape) { ... }
```

is that you end up having to code an "instanceof" switch with a case for each of the different shapes.  The repetitious code is still there, and you've replaced the static typing with something that is potentially more fragile ...

(AFAIK, there is no general / efficient algorithm for testing if two arbitrary shapes intersect.  Especially if the shapes involve curved lines.)

Comment: +1. Or if you do not want to put Circle code into Rectangle, have a helper class with static methods that does intersection calculations for all Shapes.

Comment: I thought of the rectangle.isIntersecting(this), but quickly realized that there is no really "right" place to put the code. Should it go in the Rectangle class or the Circle class? Also, how would you suggest I define the API method? You're right, as of now I have an instanceof switch but I don't like it at all.